# Highstock Area chart: multiple series navigator issue

Tags: highcharts

when i add multiple series in single chart in highstock area chart,
it'll display only first series in navigator panel.

please refer [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ughPE/20/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use series oejct in navigator and place all points from first and second series.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series

Second solution is using a addSeries for navigator like here: http://jsfiddle.net/6fFwM/

```
 window.chart.addSeries({
        name : "",
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 1,
        type: "line",
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        data : new_data,
        showInLegend:false
});
```

Comment: i refereed the example which you give , but not getting expected result. please edit my fiddle for  solution.

Comment: Why You vote down my answer, when its correct? I introduce you how to use it in the highstock, so whats wrong ? Only what you need is adapt example to your environment.

Comment: i know how to use and i already written that the example you sent is not useful to me, if you know answer than edit my fiddle. otherwise leave.

Comment: You expect prepare code instead of you, but on Stackoverflow we help each other, no alwas preparign entire code.

Comment: you are right, but current problem little bit tricky, so many question is pending even on highchart.uservoice.com regarding this problem.

Comment: When cases are in the uservoice, then will be implemented in the nearest future if gather the most votes.